# Google Analytics: How to export all data for your account in GA?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I need to export all of the Google Analytics data for an account, but I'm not seeing any exportation options within neither the admin area nor in [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/).

Am I missing this or has Google just completely left this functionality out of GA?